# constexpr в объявлении дружественной функции

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20

Код:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto operator==(const Foo<T>& lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs) -> bool;

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    friend constexpr auto operator==<T>(const Foo<T>&, const Foo<T>&) -> bool;
};
```

Нужно ли указывать constexpr в объявлении друга в данном случае? В [стандарте](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#8) нашел следующее:

> When a friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function
> template, the function parameter declarations shall not include
> default arguments, nor shall the inline, constexpr, or consteval
> specifiers be used in such a declaration.

<strike>Однако, на том же cppreference, можно найти [примеры](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering) с `friend constexpr bool operator..`, так  что я не уверен, что правильно понял вышеприведенную выдержку из стандарта.</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С++11 в этом случае нельзя использовать только `inline` спецификатор, а `constexpr` - можно.

> 8 When a friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template, the function parameter declarations shall not include default arguments, nor shall the inline specifier be used in such a declaration.

А цитата из вопроса относится к 20 или 23 стандарту.

Comment: Спасибо! Извините, С++11 указал только из-за constexpr, на самом деле действительно интересует C++20. Нашел черновик за 17-ый год, там действительно нет ни слова об constexpr. Но тогда странно, почему на cppreference примеры содержат constexpr (примеры как раз для C++20).

Comment: Кажется, разобрался - в этих примерах нет никаких шаблонов)

Comment: @isnullxbh у `partial_ordering` дружественные объявления не для специализаций шаблонных функций.